# Programatically copy one jar file into another jar file

Tags: java, jar

I want to copy a jar file in a folder with the following code

```
   public static void copyJarFile(JarFile jarFile, File destDir) throws IOException {
       String fileName = jarFile.getName();
       String fileNameLastPart = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
       File destFile = new File(destDir, fileNameLastPart);

       JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));
       Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();

       while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
           JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
           InputStream is = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);

           //jos.putNextEntry(entry);
           //create a new entry to avoid ZipException: invalid entry compressed size
           jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(entry.getName()));
           byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
           int bytesRead = 0;
           while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               jos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           }
           is.close();
           jos.flush();
           jos.closeEntry();
       }
       jos.close();
   }
```

The program works well. but when the destination is not a directory but a jar file then this program does not work. ie I want to copy one jar file into another jar file. how I can do it programmatically?

Comment: Why do you bother opening the jar file and copying each entry individually instead of copying the file itself? Also, which version of Java do you use?

Comment: i am using jdk1.7. ok can u plz tell me how to copy the whole jar file into another jar file instead of copying each entry explicitly.

Comment: OK, so do you mean you want to copy the entire contents of a jar file into another one? If yes, under some subdirectory? Your code does not make that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `I want to copy one jar file into another jar file`, what do you mean, exactly?

Suppose your original original jar is named `a.jar`, and you want to create `b.jar`. Do you mean you want all items in `a.jar` to be inside `b.jar`, just as they were? Or do you want `b.jar` to contain an entry called `a.jar` that is a complete copy of `a.jar`?

If you just wanted `b.jar` to contain all the items in `a.jar`, your current code should work, although there are much more efficient ways of doing this. If this is what you meant, I would recommend just copying the file directly.

If you wanted to add the entire `a.jar` inside `b.jar` as an entry, instead of looping through entries in `a.jar`, you would just create a `FileInputStream` from `a.jar` and read from that.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("a.jar");

jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry("a.jar"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    jos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: But one more thing plz Ben! This deletes all previous data of destination jar file and insert a new jar file in it i also want to preserve that data. That is the copying process of source jar into destination jar should not effect the previous files of destination. Plz help me once again

Comment: Unfortunately the Java's built-in Jar API doesn't allow modifying an existing jar file, which means you'd have to create a new jar file, copy all the existing entries (like you did in your original post), then add the new jar (like in my answer) before closing the `JarOutputStream`.

Comment: ok. I am creating a utility called Pooler that will add clients new algorithm provided by the clients in form of jar files my application name is Pooler.jar. According to ur answer when a new algorithm is added in my Pooler.jar project i would have to create again a new jar and copy all previous entries into new jar and then i again copy new algorithm into my new jar file and delete the previous version of jar that contains the old algorithms?

Comment: ok i should create a separate folder that should outside of Pooler.jar where i should copy client's provided jar file.

Comment: Technically, yes. However, based on your description of your application, I don't think it's going to do what you think it will. The classloader isn't going to have access to the classes inside the jars inside of `Pooler.jar` until you restart the JVM running your application. You probably want to do some research on classloaders and redesign this aspect of your application.

Comment: @BenKern " the Java's built-in Jar API doesn't allow modifying an existing jar file" that is WRONG since Java 7+

Comment: @fge If that's the case, could you point me to some documentation to that effect? As far as I can see, the Javadocs for the `java.util.jar` package don't have anything like that. I looked over the source code for jar.exe and it creates a new temp jar file, adds all required entries one-by-one, then deletes the original jar and renames the temp file to replace the original file.

Comment: @BenKern use the zip filesystem provider; not very well documented but it just works. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTNuCxPJX5g); I use this provider read only but it can be used read write

Answer (score 0):

A Jar file is just a fancy named zip file with a certain file structure and a .jar extension. So if you're able to use this to dump everything to a folder and that folder has the exact structure you're looking for, you can just zip up that directory as a zip file, and then rename that zip file `whatever.jar` instead of `whatever.zip`.

Comment: Even saying a ".jar extension" is misleading; a so-called "extesion" is just part of a file name, in spite of what all DEs would have you believe. I could call a zip file "I am a zip" or "I tell you I am text.txt".

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you have a .zip in your classpath, the JVM won't add it to your classpath, but it will add a .jar. So yes, the extension is an integral part of the file since without the extension it will never get noticed (at least in any JVM or JEE container implementation I'm aware of).